# Profile picture changes when applying other network-wide profile settings

Tags: bug, profile-picture, profile-page

I was editing my profile on StackOverflow, only changed my work title and email address.

I clicked on "apply to all network profiles" (or something like that) at the bottom of the page, then realized that (only after clicking save), my profile picture (in all stackexchange sites I was registered to) got an IdentIcon instead of the already-existing profile picture.

Was that supposed to happen? What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible work-around: [Why did my avatar change?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332880)

Comment: Yer profile picture is cool though :)

Comment: yeah, it's damned cool !

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ and JoeBlow - thanks! made by the talented Aviv Or :) http://www.avivor.com/

Comment: @JosephQuinsey my workaround was to just set it back again, and apply it network-wide again. But I was mostly wondering why it happened in the first place, and if someone in the code team is aware of that. Thanks though!